# If counter-emf is zero, why is COE violated?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electromagnetic

I've been modeling this thought experiment a for a while now:

If in a electromagnetic system, the induced emf wasn't opposing the change, but increasing it, we're getting energy from nowhere, that makes sense when I consider conservation of energy & Lenz law.

[image]

What if a motor's coil has counter-emf = 0, and has constant current with increasing angular/linear velocity over time, or a current carrying rail & rod system, where the rod is moving without any counter-emf to reduce the applied constant power(constant voltage & constant current).

I don't see how this case violates conservation of energy.
Whatever kinetic energy gained by those moving components is from the power source, likewise, for the heat lost.

Unless, I'm missing something?

Comment: I think that it would be more complicated if you take into account the field at the junctions of the rods where you'll be creating at least some fields and currents that oppose these ones.  Removing that concern, counter-emf I believe is caused by forces that oppose the motor, so if you neglect rolling friction and air resistance, it makes sense to me for counter emf to calculate to nil.  If you start to brake the motion of the roller, or push it back, naturally you would get counter emf as it begins to cross it's own field lines as they advance.

Comment: But induced emf *does* oppose the change that caused it, so the basic premise of your thought experiment is wrong.

Comment: @KH Naturally yes, but as you remove counter emf, it seems that nothing is resisting the kinetic energy, meaning, the system keeps increasing with constant force & acceleration leading to a high terminal velocity that possibly could be higher than the initial input electrical power. I tried modeling it, and it seems to violate COE if you assume -V(counter emf) = 0.

Comment: @Chu Assume the premise to be: counter-emf does not exist in that situation, or simply is at zero. So now, you have kinetic energy that's not being resisted, and it's coming from nowhere. I now change my opinion from the question statement, COE is violated since input energy = output heat( as t-reaches to infinity), but there is nothing that deals with the kinetic energy gained within the output. Therefore, counter-emf is applied to balance out Ein = Eout.

Comment: @Blurred Yeah that would make sense.  If you are simulating this, it may be that there is no geometric shape that can produce no counter EMF.  Your diagram is actually more or less the way a railgun works, although I believe if your rails are parallel the rod will tend to roll towards the source, not away.

Comment: @KH It's a thought experiment, such a system obviously does not exist.  Similar systems(in E.M) follows basic principles from electromagnetism, therefore, if there is any change in a  flux(electric/magnetic) there is a resistive variable that spawns to resist that change. In my case(referencing systems similar to the diagram) the kinetic energy gained by the system(i.e mechanical output) is resisted directly by the induced counter-emf, if that doesn't exist, you're getting KE from nowhere. Since Input energy = Output heat(after sometime).

Comment: @KH Thanks for the feedback though :D !

Comment: @Blurred, can you explain in more detail why you would expect there to be no counter-emf?  All it takes to induce it is for another field, ambient or otherwise or another part of the same field.  The most obvious source I see in this diagram is that the cylinder would tend to roll, creating significant rotational relative motion for that coil.  The other two coils, if viewed separately, would be decreasing in length as the center coil rolled, so the ends always connect to the center coil, but I believe even this small interaction, would constitute relative motion and produce back emf.

Comment: @KH You're analyzing a diagram that I set as a "basis" for a hypothetical that doesn't exist. Your analysis however is correct.

Comment: Here's an example: I have a rocket and instead of using an RS-68 on the shuttle(my basis), let's attached a warp drive!(hypothetical that does not exist). Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Kinetic energy coming from nowhere - yet another perpetual motion machine.

Comment: @Chu Sure. If you consider the hypothetical too seriously, this is another exercise to understand the importance and usefulness of fundamental laws in physics(Newton's 3rd & Lenz & Poynting to COE). And why such systems don't work.

Comment: Your hypothesis is irrational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a *very* high level...

### What you're missing is relativity.

Your statement is true in a static frame of reference, but with charges in motion, you have electro-magnetic interactions.

In a static frame (charges are fixed relative to each other), you can convert electromotive force to kinetic energy (and heat). However, in the real world, the conversion of electromotive force requires those charges to move... and moving charges disturb the fields around them.

Disturbing those fields creates E-M waves and those have to balance out to conserve energy. That's the source of "back/counter"-EMF in electromagnetics.

Comment: What is meant by: At a very high level(Are we talking about magnitudes of variables)? The rest made sound sense to me, even after I modeled the system under the assumption that counter-emf = 0, what I get for this dynamic system is kinetic energy from nowhere.  The input power source is outputting heat(Ein = Eout , assuming c-emf=0 ∴ Epowersource = Eheat + KE, ∴ Ein < Eout). So yeah, my initial view is true if the system is static(no mechanical output), but if there is a mechanical output with zero counter emf, where getting motion from nothing which does violate COE. Thanks!

Comment: "very high level" just means that I'm simplifying a lot and not using a detailed mathematical model (e.g. no equations in my answer).

Comment: Do you agree with my comment above? Is is there something lacking?

Comment: @blurred -- Static doesn't mean no mechanical output, it means no moving charges. If you have no mechanical output, but current flowing, "back/counter" EMF is maximized (that's literally how "back/counter" EMF was first observed). The reason you can't make your scenario work for CoE is because you are starting with a false assumption: no mechanical output = no moving charges; yet somehow you have heat.